# No property [propertyName] found for type [Type] when invoke findAll(pageable)

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-boot-jpa

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "report_type")
public class ReportType implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "report_name")
    private String reportName;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "active")
    private boolean active;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "report_id")
    private String reportId;
}
```

The `ReportTypeService.java` contains:

```
public Page<ReportType> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
   return reportTypeRepository.findAll(pageable);
}
```

The error I got is

```
service.ReportTypeService.findAll() with cause = 'NULL' and exception = 'No property report found for type ReportType! Did you mean 'reportId'?'

org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property report found for type ReportType! Did you mean 'reportId'?
```

From the error message my understanding is Spring boot is looking for field `report` but it doesn't exist, but I didn't pass anything except `pageable`, can anyone help on this?

Comment: Try by writing your own and check whether it is working.

Comment: I think the problem can be found in the `sort` of the `pageable`. Are you doing something like `PageRequest.of(0, 10, Sort.by("report")` ?

Comment: @DirkDeyne Thanks for your reply.  I just configured page number and page size, I didn't pass any sort request option

Comment: sure? I tested it and got basically an identical error-messages `org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property report found for type ReportType! Did you mean 'reportId'?`

Comment: Is there anything in the class reportTypeRepository which overrides the default?